# regex pattern for the following string Amby : Dexter,Dexter : Karla

Tags: c#, regex

I have a input list that takes input in the above format and put them into a comma seperated string. I would like to get strings before and after colon(:).

I tried this regex pattern

```
string[] reg = Regex.Split(x, @"^(?:[\w ]\:\s[\w]+)+$");
```

but it doesnt seem to work. Please help.

Below is my code. This is a C# console application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> input = new List<string>();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your input");
            string readinput = Console.ReadLine();
            input.Add(readinput);

            while (readinput != "")
            {
                readinput = Console.ReadLine();
                input.Add(readinput); 
            }

            string x = string.Join(",", input.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine(x);

            // using regex

            string[] reg = Regex.Split(x, @"^(?:[\w ]\:\s[\w]+)+$");

            Console.WriteLine(reg); 
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry i was not very clear but the 
input : Amby : Dexter,
        Dexter : Karla,
        Karla : Matt .....
Expected Output is Amby, Dexter, Karla, matt....

Comment: What is your expected output?  Your current regex won't match the input string you gave us.

Comment: The `^(?:[\w ]\:\s[\w]+)+$` is an anchored pattern, it makes no sense using it with `Regex.Split`.

Comment: unclear: do you want to search the complete string for strings between colons (in that case: why mention that it is comma separated?), or do you want to find the string between colons in every comma separated part of the comma separated string?

Comment: What exactly is the input, is it "Amby : Dexter,Dexter : Karla"? or "Amby : Dexter" or later "Dexter : Karla"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly... User enters some strings, and then you join them with commas. After that you want to split that string by colons?

Why don't you use simpler solution like this:

```
string[] reg = x.Split(':').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will get you started:

```
 new Regex(@"(([a-zA-Z])+(?:[\s\:\,]+))").Matches("...");
```

or this regex

```
 "\b([a-zA-Z])+\b"
```

Iterate over the MatchCollection.